# Limits- h'(0) and writing properly

Tags: calculus

1. Write the definition of the derivative of a function of $x$ as a $\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to0}$

I have no idea what this is talking about.

2. Consider
   $H(x) =
   \begin{cases}
   x(1-cos(\frac{1}{x}))   & \text{x$\neq$0} \\
   0, & \text{$x=0$}
   \end{cases}$ 
   Using the limit definition of the derivative find $H'(0)$. If that limit does not exist, explain why.
   I feel like the limit does exist, and I'm just missing something.
   A reply today would be appreciated.

Comment: For (1): The question is just asking you to write the definition of a derivative. What does your book define it as? For (2): Do you know the definition of the derivative as it is applied to this function H? Write a fraction.

Comment: That's what I did for the first part. I don't know what you mean by the second part.

Comment: @Juny Is this what you meant? And this might be helpful next time you post [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I think that made it a lot better to read too. Do you have any idea how to approach the second part of this problem? Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Juny For 1. when its says to analyze the limit as it approaches zero that is the limit process for finding the derivative at that specific point $\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)$

Comment: delta x equals 0, though.

Comment: Yes that is the limit process for evaluating the derivative.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to approach the second part? I don't know what to take the derivative of.

Comment: @Juny: You don't set $\Delta x=0$. To make typing easier I will use $w$ for $\Delta x$. For the derivative at $0$ we want the limit as $w\to 0$ of $\frac{(0+w)(1-\cos(1/(0+w))-0}{w}$. After a little simplification we want the limit as $w\to 0$ of $1-\cos(1/w)$. But this wiggles desperately between $0$ and $2$ as $w\to 0$, so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

**Limit Process**

$f'(x)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x) + f(x)}{\Delta x}$

$H'(x)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{H(x+\Delta x)+H(x)}{\Delta x}$

This is number 1 using the limit process to evaluate the derivative at $x=0$.  This is simply the limit process for evaluating the derivative using $\Delta x$.

**Part 2**

Using the answer from part 1

$H'(0)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{H(0+\Delta x)+(0)}{\Delta x}$

$H'(0)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{H(\Delta x)+H(0)}{\Delta x}$

$H'(0)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{H(\Delta x)+(0)}{\Delta x}$

$H'(0)$$=\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}$$\frac{H(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$

$H'(0)$=$\frac{H(0)}{0}$

$H'(0)$=$\frac{0}{0}$=**undefined**

The limit doesn't exist since $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate state so the slope is undefined.

Comment: I don't think it's talking about evaluating the derivative at x=0- it's just asking for the definition of the derivative at any specific point for a function of x with delta x --> 0. For the second part, would that just make the answer 0?

Comment: @Juny Yeah I just caught that, and for the second part I tried it but i think its not right exactly, I just applied what I knew for that part.